# New validation causes old migration to fail in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I added new validation to my model. Now, when I run my migrations on old database dump, I have error in the middle with `save()!` method with description: `Validation failed: User can't be blank`.

How can I avoid this problem? The only way is to edit this migration to work with database dumps now?

Comment: Make sure the respective user record is not null in the databse before doing database dump or remove the validation and put it after the database dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found to be simple, just don't use `.save` method on model, it validates all fields. Instead, use `.update`.

Comment: Or you can just use `save` instead of `save!`

Comment: It would not show me error and interrupt, but it would not save it either to database.